# magento2 - remove validation dynamically

Tags: magento2

I working with Magento 2.X I need remove the validation for some fields through javascript for example region or address.

Or is possible set the value through javascript?

I try this code by not working for me because the system me generate the message  "This is a required field."

```
 $('select[name="region_id"]').val(514)
```

[image: Page checkout]